# Can I run run-test-suite in Apache OFBiz 13.07 and how to?

Tags: ofbiz

With OFBiz 13.07.03 (https://github.com/apache/ofbiz/blob/REL-13.07.03/applications/party/ofbiz-component.xml) line 42, I run the `ant test-suite`

```
apache-ofbiz-13.07.03 ant run-test-suite -Dtest.component=party -Dtest.suiteName=PartyTests
```

The console returns the following error:

```
[java] org.ofbiz.base.start.StartupException: Cannot start() org.ofbiz.testtools.TestRunContainer (No tests found (party / PartyTests / null))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because the correct name of the test suite is all lowercased: instead of "PartyTests" you should use "partytests".
The following command should succeed:

```
ant run-test-suite -Dtest.component=party -Dtest.suiteName=partytests
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Hi Quntin, if this answer solved your problem, could you please mark the answer as "accepted": in this way the question will appear as answered/resolved. Thank you.